# Why there's a difference between Visual Studio Code functions color?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, colors

I just want to ask why the functions color in vs code is different although they are the same type of functions.

The first function appears blue (default) and the second id appears white, which is not normal:

[image]

Theme: Dark+(vs code default)

Comment: Sometimes syntax highlighting hiccups and keywords don't get colored correctly. Try deleting the `f` in `def` and typing it again. It should turn blue.

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to do with python(or python3.x) in particular. You are probably not calling that function in the program, that's why VsCode is graying it. It's a built in feature into VsCode. Just try to call that function and see what happens. Hopefully, it should work.